# Is there a way to add pull-down-to-refresh to the webview_flutter widget?

Tags: flutter, webview

I am trying to create an flutter app that will display a website inside a WebView and I would like to be able to setup a RefreshIndicator that is triggered when a user pulls down on the webview and refreshes the WebView .

I can get the WebView working but RefreshIndicator only works with vertically scrollable views. I have tried adding the WebView to a ListView as the only child but the WebView does not pull down the ListView.

I have tried putting the RefreshIndicator around the Webview, I have also tried using a PageView instead of ListView

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final url;

  WebViewContainer(this.url);

  @override
  createState() => _WebViewContainerState(this.url);
}

class _WebViewContainerState extends State<WebViewContainer> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  var _url;
  final _key = UniqueKey();

  _WebViewContainerState(this._url);

  // WebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        child: ListView(children: [
          Container(
            child: Center(child: Text('Top')),
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: WebView(
              key: _key,
              initialUrl: _url,
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                _controller.complete(webViewController);
              },
              navigationDelegate: (navigationRequest) {
                return NavigationDecision.navigate;
              },
              gestureRecognizers: Set()
                ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                    () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
              javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
                _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
              ].toSet(),
              onPageFinished: (String url) {
                print('Page Finished loading: $url');
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Center(child: Text('Bottom')),
          ),
        ]),
        onRefresh: _refreshWebView,
      ),
    );
  }
```

what I would like is a way to display just the Webview and when they pull down on the Webview that it refreshes. Another option would be if the Webview would pull down the ListView if you scroll to the top of the page in the Webview.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the current beta implementation of WebView.  The parent Scrollable (ListView in this example) needs to be able to scroll for pull down refresh.  However, it cannot scroll if you designate that to the WebView via the GestureRecognizer.  The only other way this would work is to either pull the "Top" or "Bottom" text areas you added, or to somehow detect the scroll position of the WebView

Comment: did you ever found a way to solve this ?

Comment: Meanwhile, we can all upvote the new feature request here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31027

Answer (score 0):

Well, it can be done.

1. While creating the webView, set the gestureRecognizers to EagerGestureRecognizer();
2. Implements a AllowMultipleGestureRecognizer which extends VerticalDragGestureRecognizer, override the rejectGesture() to acceptGesture();
3. Implements a RawGestureDetector, use AllowMultipleGestureRecognizer as the "gestures";
4. Put a LayoutBuilder() in the RawGestureDetector, the purpose is to get the sub-context;
5. Put your webView into the LayoutBuilder.  Now, both the webView & the RawGestureDetector can receive gesture events.
6. Implement a translation layer which translates gestures into scroll notifications.  The scroll notifications you might interested is: ScrollStartNotification, OverscrollNotification, ScrollUpdateNotification & ScrollEndNotification.  UserScrollNotification is not necessary for the RefreshIndicator.  This layer might take some time to do things right;
7. In the RawGestureDetector's callback function: onStart()/onUpdte()/onEnd(), invoke the translation layer to generate notifications.  Then use the context you get from the LayoutBuilder to call each ancestor widget who is listening to the scroll event.  Use context.visitAncestorElements() to achieve this.
8. Modify the webView's platform code (both Android & iOS), to add a listener to the YOffset.  The listener invokes the "channel" method to pass the offset to your flutter code.  The translation layer in 6 looks into the YOffset in order to generate correct notifications (e.g. OverscrollNotification or ScrollUpdateNotification).
9. Put the RawGestureDetector into a RefreshIndicator and you are DONE!

Result:
The result is quite disappointing.
The RefreshIndicator's animation causes the webView to redraw a couple of times which causes screen flicker and considerable lag.  It is definitely not a good user experience.  Flutter cannot handle heavy duty "plug-in" widgets well, any animation related operation to webView (e.g. push/pop) should be avoided.

Time wasted.